# Jboss as7 to WildFly migration weld unsatisfied dependencies for type

Tags: jboss, guice, jboss-weld, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm trying to migrate a jboss as 7 application to WildFly.
For some reason I am getting the weld unsatisfied dependencies for type  Set.

For just about every class that uses the @Inject (Using guice).
I can not think of any way for solving this and have been stuck for several hours now.

```
Exception 0:
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type 'classNameHere' with qualifires @Default 
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject cant.tell.du.services.data.syly.nbp.syll.gkfsn
at cant.tell.du.services.data.syly.nbp.syll.gkfsn(syll.java:0)

at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProbloms(Validator.java:368)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
```

Comment: Hi, can you post more about your setup and stack traces?
Without some more detailed information it will not be possible to figure the issue.

Comment: This is a really old application that works of JBoss as 7, there was not much more of a setup then adding the cdi-1.2, and the Jboss-ejb-api3.2 (from 3.1).
I will add a stack trace but its just the normal known exception

Comment: This error only tells you that Weld is not able to resolve the dependency for this injection point which indicates that you didn't supply an implementation for this interface.

Can you post your setup? Did you include at least an empty beans.xml in your deployment? I think this is still necessary for CDI 1.1

Comment: He should not try to, thouse are pojos injected by guice, weld did not try to find them in jboss 7, why is he trying to find them now.

Comment: Oh, I totally missed the point that you are using guice :/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I got the point that you are using guice instead of cdi.
You could try to exclude the weld subsystem from your deployment like so:

```
<exclude-subsystems>
    <subsystem name="weld" />
</exclude-subsystems>
```

This should disable CDI for your deployment and you should not run into the same problems anymore.

Comment: Hi, did you try to exclude the weld subsystem for your deployment and did it help?

Comment: Worked for me removing these lines from standalone.xml : 
```<extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/> ```
```<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:3.0"/> ```